# Supabase cache max-age not being respected by Chrome

Tags: caching, storage, supabase, max-age

I have updated the cache max age for my images in Supabase to 15552000 seconds (6 months), since my files will be static.

However, when I check the network tab in Chrome, the max-age is still 3600.

I have made sure that it was not because it was the old cache still working, but even after clearing the cache or waiting for the hour to pass, the max-age is still the same, 3600.

[image]

Even though the metadata of my image clearly indicates the max-age:

[image]

I am currently using the Supabase image URL instead of downloading the image, does that affect the result?

I also added an htaccess file with this code in it:

`<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|webp|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$"> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15552000, public" </FilesMatch>`

Am I missing something?

**Update**: New images uploaded do have the max-age OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing it in the Supabase Discord we determined it may have to do with the server cache, apperently with the new CDN.

To solve the issue and get a new max-age on cache, you will have to delete all the files in the storage and replace them with the same ones **with new names**.

Don't upload them through the dashboard because it will automatically set it to 3600.

If anyone is interested I opened two issues in the Supabase repo:

- One to solve the issue directly: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/11252
- Another one to be able to update the cacheControl from dashboard and from a specific function: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/11249